# tomcat project WAR does not start in OpenShift

Tags: tomcat, openshift

I have a WAR to deploy in OpenShift rhc. I got all deployment success, but the app does not start in the browser with URL http://sodaw-sodaw.rhcloud.com/soda-w/Applicationclient/index.html

my rhc logs are...
remote: Starting jbossews cartridge
remote: Found 127.10.116.129:8080 listening port
remote: Warning: Gear 53370a1b5973ca5e0500125f is using 100.0% of disk quota
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: success
remote: Activation status: success
remote: Deployment completed with status: success
To ssh://53370a1b5973ca5e0500125f@sodaw-sodaw.rhcloud.com/~/git/sodaw.git/
580bbfe..abee53b master -> master

While I run the app, I get: 
"503 Service Unavailable
No server is available to handle this request." error

I was used tomcat 6.0. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The log you show above does state "Gear 53370a1b5973ca5e0500125f is using 100.0% of disk quota", but there are other issues as well.

First of all, as de instructions state, you can deploy a war file but it must be called ROOT.war.

Second, your application has to server content at de root url, http(s)://sodaw-sodaw.rhcloud.com/ in your case.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks. But it does the same even if I run with http://sodaw-sodaw.rhcloud.com/, while put the ROOT.war in the webapps folder. Showing the same error: "503 Service Unavailable. No server is available to handle this request."

The full log:

Building git ref 'master', commit f867011
Activating deployment
+ '[' ROOT.war ']'
Starting jbossews cartridge
Found 127.11.125.129:8080 listening port
Gear 5339c461e0b8cdc5690000bf is using 100.0% of disk quota
Activation status: success
Deployment completed with status: success
ssh://5339c461e0b8cdc5690000bf@sodaw-sodaw.rhcloud.com/~/git/sodaw.git/

Comment: Your deployment still states "Gear 5339c461e0b8cdc5690000bf is using 100.0% of disk quota" This usually means your application is being terminated.